# Re-creating transaction flow for specific wallets (BSC)

Tags: wallets, etherscan, bsc, history, binance

I was thinking of doing some good for the community. By my general profession, I am a lawyer and an Anti-money laundering specialist. I wanted to graph some transactions tracking funds from their origin exchanges and filing police reports for rug-pull projects on BSC. Police tend to accept cases that are pretty much solved and then handed in so additional investigations before reports are essential.

Ideal case scenarios are where I can track money flow from a CEX to a wallet which is then further used for contract creation, however, in some cases I have endured something strange. For some wallets history starts with OUT transaction not IN. What it looks like in the BSC scan is that the wallet was able to make a transaction and pay the TX fee although there is no transaction that would show that it had received any BNB. So logically, if there is no BNB in the wallet - transactions can not be made.

My question is - why are some wallet histories starting with OUT transactions? If there is more to it, how can I access the full history?

Cheers

Comment: Can you include a link of such a transaction starting with an OUT?

Comment: I've noticed that bscscan does not display the full transaction history, but I want to confirm with an example before providing a more detailed answer.